# Centos 6.4. building rpm for cups 1.7

Tags: linux, centos, cups, rpm

I try to build rpm from source by running

```
rpmbuild -ta cups-1.7.0-source.tar.gz  --without dbus
```

but get

```
Processing files: cups-1.7.0-1.x86_64
error: File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/cups-1.7.0-1.x86_64/usr/share/cups/usb
error: File not found by glob: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/cups-1.7.0-1.x86_64/usr/share/cups/usb/*
```

What should I do? What package is it? I found nothing in google.

Comment: What is the point of this? CentOS already includes CUPS and it probably is not a good idea to try to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to build as a regular user.

```
sudo yum install rpmdevtools
rpmdev-setuptree
cd ~/rpmbuild/SRPMS
yumdownloader --noplugins --source cups
rpmbuild --rebuild cups*src.rpm
```

I would normally just edit ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/cups.spec to change the configure options and build with rpmbuild -ba, but it does look like you can pass those configure options in directly, like your example, if certain conditions are met:

http://rpm5.org/docs/api/conditionalbuilds.html